# Button that only works once in flash actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this collecting item game which u have to collect enough "stars" in order to acess a button. After I clicked the "star" button, it suppose to disappear and never appear again. However, when using this script, although the button disappear once I clicked it, when I returned to the frame after going to another frame, it appeared again! pls help!

```
    star1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotstar);

    function gotstar(event:MouseEvent){
stars++;
star1.x = -500;
}
```

Comment: it because when using the timeline, if you have a keyframe that has the item, it will get created again when the playhead reaches that keyframe.

Answer (score 3):

Are you coding on the frames themselves? If so every time you enter a frame it will run every piece of contained code, even if it has already ran once.  A solution to this would be to use a document class to track the progress of the game.

Comment: Does this mean that when you use frames on a MovieClip, Flash recreates the frame from scratch each time the MC reaches that frame? Good thing I'm stuck with Sprites that do what `I` want them to do, and don't have any implicit weird behavior.

Comment: Basically yes. Any code on the frame itself is executed every time the frame is entered meaning any variables declared are re-initialized.  A good solution is to take this code you want to apply to the whole movie/game and place it in a class in an actionscript (.as) file - it can seem much more complicated at first but once you're past the initial bumps it keeps your code completely separate and gives you much more control over it.  This is a very good tutorial I used to learn the basics: http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2008/09/17/avoider-game-tutorial-1/

Comment: Since I'm already controlling everything via code, there's NO WAY I would bother with writing timeline codes. This is a great piece of information regarding debugging timeline code of someone else, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove it from the stage if I understand.

try this instead of star1.x = -500;

stage.removeChild(star1);

Answer (score 0):

`star1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotstar); 
 star1.parent.removeChild(star1);` 
in the click handler code (`gotstar`) should help
however posting your `.fla` file might be useful for better understanding